# CPQ: How to use Selection Rule based on Product Option criteria?

Tags: cpq

We have the following scenario:

We have two bundle products: B1 and B2
Also we have two Products that act as Product Options for B1 and B2: PO1 and PO2

In gerneral the bundle configuration looks like this:

```
B1    
-> PO1    
-> PO2

B2
-> PO1
-> PO2
```

So both bundle parents have both add-on products set up as Product Options.

Now comes the challenge:

Depending on the market that the quote is made out to (via field on Quote), the options should be made (un)available.

E.g. if quote is made out to EMEA market, B1 can be sold with PO1 but not with PO2. If it's made out to APAC, B1 can be sold only with PO2 but not PO1.
For B2 it might be the other way around: EMEA = B1 + PO2 and APAC = B2 + PO1.

So the actual availability of my child products cannot be set on the Product level but need to be set on the Product Option level (i.e. Child Product PO1 is available for market EMEA for bundle Parent B1).

As far as I can see, Selection Rules won't allow me to remove option based on values set up on the Product Option record.

Does anyone have an idea or pointer in the right direction of how to achieve this?